# How to output a string statement using an if statement in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm doing a problem where I need to find out if the user is old enough or not to drink. The user inputs their birthday, and they have to be born on or before Feb. 1993 to be legal. Here's what I got so far.

```
#User inputs their birthday. 
year = int(input("Enter your birth year(as a number): "))
month = int(input("Enter your birth month(as a number): "))

#Finding out if they are old enough to drink or not
found=False
if (year<=1993):
    found ==True
    print("You are old enough to drink in Washington")
elif (month<=2):
    found ==True
    print("You are old enough to drink in Washington")
elif (month>=3):
    found ==True
    print("You aren't 21 yet")
```

When I input 1993, 3. It will say You are old enough to drink, when it's not supposed to.

Comment: `==` is not used for assignment, use `=`.

Comment: I don't understand the down and close votes. This guy is confused and we can help him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should trace out the logic of your statements.

I might try this instead:

```
found=False
if year < 1993:   # If less than 93, then month doesn't matter
    found = True
elif (year == 1993) and (month <= 4):   # If 1993, check month
    found = True

if found:
    print("You are old enough to drink in Washington")
else:
    print("You aren't 21 yet")
```

You might think about using the `date` module to get the year and month, instead of fixing the value so someone has to edit and update the program each month.

Comment: +1 haha can you believe my answer started out with the same phrase? "trace your own logic"?

Comment: I would also remove the unnecessary parentheses.

Comment: Pretty funny upside... I don't mind the parens in compound statements but yes it is cleaner when there is just one.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use code more like that shown below.  The month test that you have is a problem since it doesn't all test the year.  Your code also doesn't need the elif at the end since it can simply be an else.

```
found=False
if year<1993 or (year==1993 and month<=2):
    found =True
    print("You are old enough to drink in Washington")
else:
    found =True
    print("You aren't 21 yet")
```

Comment: Nice to combine with the `or`. The `found == True` should be just one equal sign for assignment, and probably `False` in the second case (not clear what they want it for), and isn't really used here anyway.

Comment: @beroe Thanks.  I wasn't paying attention to the `found` variable since it wasn't being used and I just left it as it was in the original.  I've edited now.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm. Here is two line code ..

```
found = (year<1993 or (year==1993 and month<=2)) and True or False
print "You are old enough to drink in Washington" if found else "You aren't 21 yet".
```